# I keep getting an error on this google app sheet for spotify api playlist pull any idea how to fix it?

Tags: javascript

The error I receive is the following:

> Error fetching tracks: Could not fetch tracks. Check playlist ID and
> authorization.

The ID is correct in the spread sheet as are my client ID And secret.

Here is the code:

```
var clientId = 'b5f553f554334b96ac293b9ba00e1f49';
var clientSecret = '243848b1d655497e8db6aac7c477fd63';
var accessToken = '';

function getSpotifyAccessToken() {
  var url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(clientId + ':' + clientSecret),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    payload: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  accessToken = data.access_token;
}

function getNewTracks(playlistId, lastTrackId) {
  var url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/' + playlistId + '/tracks';
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }
  };
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var tracks = data.items;
    if (tracks === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Could not fetch tracks. Check playlist ID and authorization.');
    }
    var newTracks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
      var track = tracks[i].track;
      if (track.id === lastTrackId) {
        break;
      }
      newTracks.push(track);
    }
    return newTracks;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error fetching tracks: ' + error.message);
  }
}

function checkPlaylistsForNewTracks() {
  // Refresh access token before processing playlists
  getSpotifyAccessToken();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var playlistColumn = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
  var lastTrackColumn = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
  var emailColumn = sheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
  var playlists = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < playlistColumn.length; i++) {
    var playlistId = playlistColumn[i][0].split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    var lastTrackId = lastTrackColumn[i][0];
    try {
      var newTracks = getNewTracks(playlistId, lastTrackId);
      if (newTracks.length > 0) {
        var email = emailColumn[i][0];
        var subject = 'New tracks added to playlist';
        var message = 'The following tracks have been added to the playlist:\n\n';
        for (var j = 0; j < newTracks.length; j++) {
          var track = newTracks[j];
          var position = j + 1;
          var trackName = track.name;
          var trackUrl = track.external_urls.spotify;
          message += position + '. ' + trackName + ' (' + trackUrl + ')\n';
        }
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
        sheet.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue(newTracks[0].id);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log('Error fetching new tracks: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

I double checked my client id and secret. I double checked the playlist ID. And I just can't see why I keep getting the error

Comment: Pretty sure that you haven't set authorization in your google dev console. Did you?

Comment: You can't use Client Credentials to get playlist tracks when the playlist is publicly shown on someone's profile. Using the Get Playlist endpoint, you can check if _public_ is set to _true_.